# Excel to MySQL dec2hex

Tags: mysql, excel

I need help swapping an EXCEL formula to MySQL formula.

I have the following number that will be in a column called DEC = 005341009450614

I need to break it into three parts and do a DEC2HEX conversion on each and concatenate the results. In EXCEL I would do this:

=CONCATENATE(DEC2HEX(MID(A1,1,5),4),DEC2HEX(MID(A1,6,2),2),DEC2HEX(MID(A1,8,8),6))

My question is how could a replicate this in MySQL?

I have tried:

```
SELECT CONCAT(HEX(SUBSTRING(`DEC`,1,5)),HEX(SUBSTRING(`DEC`,6,2)),HEX(SUBSTRING(`DEC`,8,8))) FROM `convert`
```

But that gives me "303032373830373039343430333437"

Where the results should be:

"02160A903476"

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert any integer to hex in MySQL just use the `HEX` function:

```
SELECT HEX(<number>);
```

The input parameter is a `BIGINT` or a string so this should suffice for large numbers.